# Позиционирование объекта в пространстве

Tags: алгоритм, позиционирование

Имеется объект 3D модели(для простоты берем куб), который помечен 3 маркерами лежащими не на одной прямой. В пространстве задается положение маркеров, необходимо выставить объект так чтобы заданные маркеры на объекте совпали с маркерами в пространстве?

Кто знает, подскажите в какую сторону копать? Буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Можно рассчитать смещение от маркеров до начала координат куба

Comment: Вопрос не столько с позицией объекта сколько с его ориентацией в пространстве. Есть какое то простое решение может кто знает?

Comment: В сторону обращения матрицы размером 3x3?

Comment: @VladD а как это вяжется с маркерами?

Comment: @KingPeas: Ну, предположим, матрица X преобразования координатной системы, в которой даны маркеры, в координатную систему, в которой находятся ваши метки, неизвестна. Умножение этой матрицы на столбец координат исходного маркера даст положение в пространстве. Составляем матрицу из трёх исходных координат-столбцов (A), а также из целевых координат (B). Получаем AX = B, X = A^(-1)B.

Comment: что имеется ввиду под маркерами ?? можно ли маркеры рассматривать как 3мерные точки ?

Comment: @ampawd да это именно точки на поверхности объекта